# How to depend the length of one token on the value of another token?

Tags: antlr, binary-data, antlr4

I want to tokenize some binary data where the length of some parts depend on the value of a previous token. You can think of that as follows:

```
<length><binary data>
```

Let’s say *length* is two bytes unsigned integer that denotes the length of *binary data* in bytes.

How can I implement this correlation with ANTLR 4?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to extend ANTLR's input-streams. As of this moment the only input streams, [`ANTLRInputStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRInputStream.java) and [`ANTLRFileStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRFileStream.java), are backed up by a `char[]` which may not suit your requirement to match any kind of binary data.

To make the lexer context sensitive as you described, you could:

- match an `UNSIGNED` number token, and once this matches, initialize an instance variable (`bytesToConsume`) with this value;
- once this `bytesToConsume` has been set, consume bytes/chars as long as this `bytesToConsume` is larger than 0<sup>!</sup>
- of course, as soon as `bytesToConsume` has been initialized, you don't want to match a `UNSIGNED` token<sup>!</sup>

<sup>!</sup> these checks are performed by [semantic predicates](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Semantic+Predicates) `{boolean-expression}?`.

A demo:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {

  private int bytesToConsume = -1;         

  boolean binary() {
    if(bytesToConsume < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    bytesToConsume--;
    return true;
  }
}

parse
 : block* EOF
 ;

block
 : UNSIGNED BINARY
 ;

UNSIGNED 
 : {!binary()}? 
   [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] {bytesToConsume = Integer.parseInt(getText(), 16);}
 ;

BINARY
 : ({binary()}? . )+
 ;
```

A driver class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("03aaa0Fbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb01c"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree tree = parser.parse();
    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
  }
}
```

Test it by doing:

### *nix

```
java -jar antlr-4.0-complete.jar T.g4
javac -cp .:antlr-4.0-complete.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-4.0-complete.jar Main
```

### Windows

```
java -jar antlr-4.0-complete.jar T.g4
javac -cp .;antlr-4.0-complete.jar *.java
java -cp .;antlr-4.0-complete.jar Main
```

And you'll see the following being printed to the console (I added indentation though):

```
(parse 
  (block 03 aaa) 
  (block 0F bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb) 
  (block 01 c) 
  <EOF>)
```

### EDIT

Perhaps something cleaner is possible by making use of ANTLR4's [lexical modes](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexicalModes). However, I'm quite new to v4 and I don't know if this is possible since you want to pop back to the default lexical scope once a certain amount of bytes/chars are consumed instead of a clear end in a BINARY-mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and please excuse my late reply. I think that’s the way to solve it, having a counter for the bytes to consume. I’m also new to ANTLR and I guess it’ll take some time until I can give you a more decent feedback to your suggestions.